# Is there a better way to connect 2 tables than the iterative approach?

Tags: java, database, algorithm, data-structures

Here is what I've got:

- I want to create a connector between 2 identical tables
- each one of them is generated by a different tool
- the 1st one is a `XLS` table and the other one is a `Excel` table (not very important because I can see each row as an object in JAVA)
- I know a modification was made when the "Date modified" changes

Is there a more effective way to update a table if a modification has been made in the other one, than the iterative approach?

Comment: XLS is an older format used by Microsoft Excel. By Excel I was referring to the actual format XLSX.

Comment: My databases are 2, separated (different documents) spreadsheets.

Comment: A spreadsheet is not a database.

Comment: Dear @Raedwald , please search for the definition of a database.

Answer (score 0):

One way or another you're going to need to compare the actual values within the excel file if you don't want to use the date modified property to determine a modification. There isn't any flag within a files property that says "Hey, this was changed since you last looked at it" other than the date modified property.

The other way to determine it would be to compare the actual value of the file against the last search but that could become very time consuming depending on the size of the file.

I think the way you're doing it is the most efficient.